# request.method getting defaulted to GET in Flask

Tags: python, post, flask

I have created a form in Flask, and want to submit certain values which need to be processed.But the method used is getting defaulted to GET even though I have specified the method as post in my form

These are the the relevant code files:
app.py

```
@app.route('/test',methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
    print(request.method)
    error = None
    try:

        if request.method == "POST":

            first_name = request.form['firstname']
            last_name = request.form['lastname']
            flash(first_name)
            flash(last_name)


            return render_template("test.html")
        else:

            return "Wrong"

    except Exception as e:

        return str(e)
```

test.html

```
<form method="post" class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="">

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- First name -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{request.form.firstname}}" class="form-control">
                            <label for="materialRegisterFormFirstName">First name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Last name -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{request.form.lastname}}" class="form-control">
                            <label for="materialRegisterFormLastName">Last name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- File Upload -->
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="file" id="fileupload" class="form-control">


                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

The method is getting defaulted to post and the response "Wrong" on loading 127.0.0.1:5000/test. The method is always GET

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="/test" method="post">

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- First name -->
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{request.form.firstname}}" class="form-control">
                        <label for="materialRegisterFormFirstName">First name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- Last name -->
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{request.form.lastname}}" class="form-control">
                        <label for="materialRegisterFormLastName">Last name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- File Upload -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="file" id="fileupload" class="form-control">


            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

By adding the "route" to the action attribute and defining the method of submission of form, you can perform the desired objective.

Comment: I had added the method="post" attribute beforehand. Now even after I have defined the action="/test" the method is still GET